# Diff eq, integrating factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

If the question is: $x\dfrac{dy}{dx} + 6x = 3x^2$, would I begin solving by dividing everything by $x$ so that I could have a linear function?

Comment: Yes, and you can directly integrate both sides with respect to $x$ to solve the differential equation.

Comment: This question is titled incorrectly, this is a separation of variables problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes divide by $x$ and then take terms on right side and integrate.

Answer (score 1):

You would indeed:

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}+6x=3x^2\implies \frac{dy}{dx}+6=3x,\quad x\neq 0$$

Comment: would this still be considered linear?

Comment: @RobertMiller Yes